# How should I store a extremely large Data Type

Tags: java, largenumber

I am currently posed with an issue regarding a super large number input. The number may range from 0 - 10^50. I have done research regarding this, but I did not run into anything that could help me. The closest thing was a BigInteger, but that does not help with my program as it prevents editing the Big Integer variable although it can store infinitely large numbers. I also tried doubles, but they did weird things to my program when doing operations on the numbers. Any suggestions or work-around?

Comment: Why do you need to edit `BigInteger`s instead of using the methods they provide right there to do math on them and get out new ones?  `BigInteger` is almost certainly the right solution, you just need to use them as intended.

Comment: In `BigInteger` library provided by Java , you have almost everything. Please, let us know what operations you are going to perform.

Comment: If, rather than infinite-precision _integers_,  you need infinite-precision real numbers (and can live with infinite-precision rational approximations of them)  there's also `BigDecimal`.

Comment: My goal is to store this number and then add up all possible n digit iterations. Because Big Integer does not allow this, I would not be able to do all of the primitive data functions such as arrays.

Comment: Not sure what an "n-digit _iteration_" is, but does it mean you need access to individual digits (or chunks of digits) within the giant numbers?

Comment: yes, so basically say you have a number 1234 and 2 as input. The n -digit iteration would then be 2- digit iterations of 1234, so 12, 23, 34 would be the output

Comment: That isn't important though, my main goal is to findout a work-around for this issue

Comment: Well, you can use combinations of division and remainder by powers of 10 to extract digits (e.g., to extract 23 from 1234, you'd do 1234 / 10 = 123, then 123 %100 = 23.  Or just convert the number to a `String` and use `substring` on the result to get at pieces (e.g., "1234".substring(1,3)="23").

Comment: how would i do .tostring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create and edit BigInteger In java, e.g.:

```
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger("3");
bigInteger = bigInteger.pow(600);
bigInteger = bigInteger.add(new BigInteger("20"));
bigInteger = bigInteger.subtract(new BigInteger("20"));
bigInteger = bigInteger.multiply(new BigInteger("20"));
bigInteger = bigInteger.divide(new BigInteger("20"));
```

And you can get any part of BigInteger as an Integer, e.g.:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(bigInteger.toString().substring(3, 8));
```

I hope this will help you.